# Why using $1 on codeIgniter route.

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is the meaning of this line and why using $1? I'm beginner to frameworks.

```
 $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Thanks.

Comment: the :any becomes $1, if you had for example $route['(:any)/(:any)'] you could Do pages/view/$1/$2

Comment: coz of regex, read about regular expression

Comment: Thanks all to answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated, `$route['(:any)']` will match any URL, so place your other custom routes before the "**catch-all**" route:

`$1` would be whatever matched by `(:any)` group - which is, really, anything. Whatever you add will get passed as the parameter for view method in pages controller.

in this example you are telling CI that anything that goes to login with any parameter like login/john will proceed to your home/bacon/john (:any) will match all string and integer if you use (:num) it will only match integer parameters like

```
$route['login/(':num')'] = 'home/bacon/$1'
```

`$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` means that anything you type on the url will proceed to pages/view/$1 the $1 here is the parameter you would like to pass to a controller/method example

```
$route['login/(:any)'] = 'home/bacon/$1';
```

in this config you are specifying that if a url login has a integer after it like login/1234, you would like it to redirect to home/bacon/1234 if you don't know how many parameters you would like to pass you could try `$route['login/(:any).*'] = 'home/bacon/$1'` more on this could be read at

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Thanks in advance for answer me.